# jquery replace query

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to alter the `href` attribute for all anchor tags within a particular `div`.

```
<div id="xyx">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="xyz/-1"/></li>
        <li><a href="abc/-1"/></li>
        <li><a href="cab/-1"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
<div id="xyx">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="xyz/-2"/></li>
        <li><a href="abc/-2"/></li>
        <li><a href="cab/-2"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i.e. I want to replace `-1`'s to `-2`'s.

How can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: Please use the {} icon to section off your code so that it is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method, and pass a [function](http://api.jquery.com/attr#attr2) to it. This executes the function on each element within the jQuery set, changing the provided attribute to the value returned by the function.

jQuery passes the current value of the attribute as the second parameter of the function (which will be current "href" value in this case), so we simply [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the `-1` occurances with `-2`.

```
$('#xyx a').attr('href', function(i, href) { 
    return href.replace('-1','-2'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#xyx ul li a').attr('href',function(i,href){ 
    return href.replace('-1','-2'); 
});
```

- `$('#xyx ul li a')` target the proper `<a>` elements.
- Call the [`attr()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to reference the `href` attribute.
- Pass a function that will be invoked once for each `<a>` element.
- Have the function perform a [`.replace()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the `href` and return the result to `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#xyx ul").find("li:nth-child(1) a").attr("href", "url");
```

You can change the number "1" to whichever number link you need.